# Is there an fast open-source portscanner?

Tags: security, network-adapter

Looking for a fast open-source c# port scanner ? Using handshake layer, pcap. Want some example for studying purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Luba Portscanner](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luba-portscanner/).